# Нужна ли запятая в предложении? Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Когда нужно точно сказать(,) кто едет в путешествие?"

Answer (score 2):

***Когда нужно точно сказать, кто едет в путешествие?***

Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед союзным словом КТО.